# Set cron environment variable with puppet

Tags: cron, puppet

I'm confused about using the [environment attribute](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#cron-attributes) of puppet's cron type. It seems like a weird place to set the PATH because then if I have multiple cron jobs I want to set up it seems like they will collide. Shouldn't it be set in a place that's global to all cron jobs for a user in addition to a specific one per cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Ben, it makes perfect sense for cron jobs in my opinion. Consider this, as an example: there's a tool called Composer for dependency management in PHP, and say I'd like to schedule automatic updates to my dependencies via cron. If there are numerous dependencies and/or it just takes too long to update them all, the tool will timeout, and that's why it accepts COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT environment variable. Thus by setting

```
environment => 'COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000',
```

I would effectively change the timeout for this particular case without touching anything else.

Hope it makes sense and cleared the air a bit.

Comment: I understand why you might want to set an environment variable for your specific cron job, but I still don't understand how to set a global environment variable that affects multiple cron jobs like PATH. That's the part this question is really asking about.

Comment: Ben, read your question once again, and the only thing I can think of doing here is the following:

    Cron {
      environment => 'PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin',
    }

This will set "environment" for all cron resources, and I believe you can then add more environment variables by concatenating to the default like so:

cron { "my-command"
  environment +> '...',
}

Comment: that doesn't work: "All resource specifications require names". if i specify a name then i get: "-":15: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the env variables will conflict with each other. The cron resource seems to set the variable at command execution time. so it shouldn't say set during other cron jobs.

eg.

```
# Puppet Name: pe-mcollective-metadata
0,15,30,45 * * * * /opt/puppet/sbin/refresh-mcollective-metadata
# Puppet Name: report_baseline
0 20 * * * PATH=/opt/puppet/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin /opt/puppet/bin/puppet inspect 1> /dev/null
```

So you can see here that the refresh-mcollective-metadata job does not have the PATH variable set when ran but the report_baseline job does.

Comment: I tested this as well and on Ubuntu/Puppet 3.3, the environment variable is set in a separate line *before* the job.